# After rendering 3D text in PS it looks like a text layer is above it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, 3d

Sorry for confusing title.  After I rendered my text 3D it looks like there is another text layer above the render that is red, even though there isn't.  How can I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After messing with some of the Front Bevel settings I found that when I changed my Diffuse color to a black it fixed it.  Don't know why, but it did.  :)

[image]